# Understanding closure returned from function

Tags: javascript, closures

I’m having problems understanding when returning `second` (in line 8). Is it returned to `first`? And why do I need to use parentheses with the variable that I assigned to first after doing so? For example: `fn()`. Why can’t I just use `fn`?

```js
function first() {
  let a = 0
  let b = 10

  function second() {
    a++
    b++
    console.log(a, b)
  }
  
  return second
}

const fn = first()

fn()
fn()
```

Comment: Your question isn't really clear - but `fn()` actually *calls* the function and thereby executes the code inside. `fn` on its own as a statement doesn't actually do anything observable.

Comment: No, `second` is returned _from_ `first`, not _to_ `first`. It is returned to `fn` as the value of the binding. Both `first` and `first()` are functions. Why do you expect `fn;` to do anything?

Answer (score 0):

Your `first()` function returns a function (`second()`).  So the variable `fn` is initialized to have that returned function as its value.

Because `fn` is a function, to get a value from it `fn` has to be *called* as a function, `fn()`. Without the `()`, it's just a reference to the function. Calling the function makes it do what it does, which in this case is to increment those variables and log the values to the console.

Comment: Thank you with this I was able to get the concept

Answer (score 0):

If you wrote `const fn = first`, `fn` would just become an alias for the function `first`.

Conversely, function `first` returns `second`, a local function defined inside `first` that accesses local variables `a` and `b` from the current invocation. This creates a special thing that captures these variables, allowing them to survive exiting from function `first` invocation. This thing is called a *closure*. It behaves like the function `second`, but refers to the specific set of variables `a` and `b` from the original call to `first()` that returned the closure.

As coded, `const fn = first()` defines a variable `fn` initialized to the return value of calling function `first()`, which is a closure of function `second` with the variables of the function call `first()` captured ('a' and 'b').

Each time you call `fn()`, the local variables `a` and `b` in the capture are incremented and their values are written to the console.

These variables can only be accessed by this particular closure of function `second`.  Calling `first()` again will return a different closure with its variables `a` and `b` initialized to `0`.

If you just wrote `fn` without the `()`, it would not do anything. You have to use the `()` to *call* the closure, just like a function.  If function `second` took 2 arguments in its definition, you would pass them as `fn(1, 2)`

Answer (score 0):

`first()` return `function second` declaration, along with its lexical environment.

so,

```
const fn = function second() {
    a++
    b++
    console.log(a, b)
  }
```

Eventually to call a function defined as function expression " () " is required,
in this case `fn()`